# TreeView Private variable clearing

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I created a private variable

```
private TreeView currentFullTree;
```

After that I run through a database and create a nice treeview with parent, child, child nodes. That works fine also.  Once the treeview is created I set my private variable to

```
currentFullTree = treeView1;
```

That populates perfectly fine and I can even extract each node and re-create the tree exactly how it looked originally from a different function.

Now this is where I'm getting lost.  I've created a filter/search function separate from where I created the treeview or re-create the treeview.  I want to only display the nodes that match the text provided. Before I perform the search I do a `treeView1.Nodes.Clear();` so it looks nice and isn't cluttery.

When I do this, it also empties out my private variable I created! I'm not entirely sure why it is doing this. I was thinking since it is just a `TreeView` variable I would be able to store my treeview in there and access it as I please.  I'm not sure if it's something silly I'm overlooking, but any help is appreciated.

Thanks,
    Tim

Comment: _When I do this, it also empties out my private variable I created! I'm not entirely sure why it is doing this._  You will need to read up on "reference types" to understand that behaviour. Here's a good link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5057267/what-is-the-difference-between-a-reference-type-and-value-type-in-c

Comment: Thank you! That was very informative!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `currentFullTree` and `treeView1` are pointing to the same object because those variables are of [reference type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/4d43ts61(v=vs.90).aspx).

Either you have to keep copy of whole tree or just tree nodes.

```
private TreeView currentFullTree;
private List<TreeNode> treeNodes;
```

and before clearing tree just add them to the list:

```
treeNodes.AddRange(treeView1.Nodes.OfType<TreeNode>());
treeView1.Nodes.Clear();
```

and when you want to show full tree (original) then add nodes from list back to tree view.

Comment: Thanks, that really helped out.  This is the first time I've ever run into anything like this, so I was even struggling figuring out how to search what my problem is.

Answer (score 2):

Your variable is only a reference to an object.

You need to clone it to be able to have different treeview (one for reference and one for display).

see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173109.aspx

this may also be usefull for cloning the tree https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treenode.clone%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

but be aware of this:

> Remarks
>
> The tree structure from the tree node being cloned and below is
>   copied. Any child tree nodes assigned to the TreeNode being cloned are
>   included in the new tree node and subtree.
>
> The Clone method performs a shallow copy of the node. If the value of
>   the Tag property is a reference type, both the original and cloned
>   copy will point to the same single instance of the Tag value.